# GZip stream compression with Delphi (optionally with tar)

Tags: delphi, stream, gzip, zlib, deflate

I am searching and searching since hours to create a valid .tar.gz file using streams in Delphi 10.

I was able to solve the tarball part using [LibTar](http://www.destructor.de/), which works well.

After some searching I also found examples to decompress gzip data using just `System.ZLib`. The secret lies in the WindowBits parameter:

```delphi
// 31 bit wide window = gzip only mode
DecompStream:= TZDecompressionStream.Create(SourceStream, 15 + 16);
TarStream:= TTarArchive.Create(DecompStream);
TarStream.Reset;
while TarStream.FindNext(DirRec) do {...} TarStream.ReadFile(TargetStream);
```

Great! But is it really possible that `System.ZLib` is able to decompress gzip (I guess by just ignoring the gzip header by that +16?), but is not able to create such header by itself? Whatever I try, I only get a file that cannot be opened by 7zip or WinRar, because the header is missing.

Maybe it just can't work, because the gzip header contains a checksum, so it's not possible to write the header without knowing the following data. How to solve this? Edit: this is wrong, see comments: crc32 is in the trailer.

It seems, many others also have this problem - I found and tried multiple solutions to add this header, but nothing really worked and everything requires adding long units (not nice but acceptable) or even DLLs (not acceptable for me).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1838699/how-can-i-decompress-a-gzip-stream-with-zlib

Comment: So you are telling me (at least if feels like - I can only guess), I could have known about compressing gzip with delphi by finding and reading a non-delphi question about DEcompression using zlib, and there the second answer titled with "python", which just mentions compression by that small "(de-)" somewhere in the middle of the text, and that makes my question and answer obsolete? Yes, it's all there, somewhere. But for me it was really hard to find, so I hope my question and answer will help others now. If you google for "delphi gzip compression" you will hopefully understand the problem.

Comment: No, I'm just adding a link to another pertinent question so that the two questions are linked together. You can see the list of linked topics on the right hand side.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32498990/decompress-deflatestream-c-in-delphi  Here's another one that is Delphi related.

Comment: This unit contains a good implementation of compress/uncompress stream in the Gzip format: https://github.com/mike-lischke/GraphicEx/blob/master/3rd%20party/DelphiZlib/ZLibExGZ.pas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The secret lies in the `WindowBits` parameter - sounds familiar? :)

Believe it or not, compressing to gzip just works the same way! I couldn't find this anywhere using Google, or in the Embarcadero documentation/help. But have a look at this comment in the `System.ZLib` source of Delphi Tokyo:

> Add 16 to windowBits to write a simple gzip header and
>   trailer around the compressed data instead of a zlib wrapper. The
>   gzip header will have no file name, no extra data, no comment, no
>   modification time (set to zero), no header crc, and the operating
>   system will be set to 255 (unknown).

It works:

```delphi
TargetStream:= TFileStream.Create(TargetFilename, fmCreate);
CompressStream:= TZCompressionStream.Create(TargetStream, zcDefault, 15 + 16);
TarStream:= TTarWriter.Create(CompressStream);
TarStream.AddStream(SourceStream1, SourceFilename1, Now);
TarStream.AddString(SourceString2, SourceFilename2, Now);
```

Comment: There is always a CRC to verify file integrity in the gzip format. What is not there is a separate _header_ CRC, for just the 10-byte header. Not a problem.

Comment: Aaaah, thanks, @MarkAdler! Hmm, but that means that the `TZCompressionStream` has to buffer all the data in memory, because it has to wait for the end to know size and crc for putting it to the header (just checked the header format). I didn't expect that. Ok, for the records: I remove my "I think it's bad not to have a checksum to verify file integrity." from the answer...

Comment: No, the gzip format puts the size and CRC in the trailer, not the header.

Comment: That was also my first logical conclusion, but I wasn't able to verify this here http://zlib.org/rfc-gzip.html#header-trailer - the title mentions a trailer, but not the text. So I found some posting somewhere else, that the trailer is just a #0 -> 10+1=11 (wrong). - But now, thanks for your help, I scrolled a page up from this chapter and understand :) thank you for helping and your work. It can all be very misleading when you try to save time, especially when you make wrong assumptions, like thinking that windowBits might be something to skip unknown headers on decompression. (continued...)

Comment: When you google around, you find many projects using zlib for the compression, but manually putting a gzip wrapper around it, using a lot of own code - again a source for wrong assumptions. Even now with knowing what to look for, I don't see many people using it correctly (I only looked for Delphi code!). Is it new? Since when is this supported, @MarkAdler? I'm new to it, and anyway not the linux guy, so to me, it was a Delphi system unit and Embarcadero should add such important things in their documentation. I hope this question will help others with the same problem.

Comment: Looks like in-memory gzip was added in zlib 1.2.1, in 2003.

Comment: I know it's not good to make this conversation any longer, but let me remark: if someone has any better tar code than I'm using, please tell :) (but it works and I'm happy with this) - maybe it's an idea to include tar support in future zlib versions? ;-) Would be really great, but no reply necessary.